# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on line 20

Tags: php

I get the following error when testing my registering form:

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on line 20

It says that this line of code is wrong:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, the message is crystal clear... You pass a function result as second argument to the `bindParam()` method which expects a variable. Take a look at the documentation.: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php  The second argument is defined as a _reference_ to an argument. That is not possible for a function call result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable needs to be passed by ref, your passing the output of a function.

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

Would resolve the issue

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Note the ampersand before the variable.